# PHP: XML file contains strange @attribute-tags after saving with asXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to modify an xml-file after uploading to a Drupal-Page. I use the rules-module for this, to do some changes to the file and save it in a new location on server. That works fine, but in the saved new file there are some <@attribute>-tags, which shouldn't be there.
What I do is:

```
$fileUri = $xml_file->uri;  
$xmlDaten = simplexml_load_file($fileUri);
foreach ($xmlDaten->xpath('//Reference') as $reference) {
  dpm($reference);
}
$xmlDaten->asXML('sites/example.de/files/xml/xml_import.xml');
```

I don't do any manipulation, only looping and showing the reference-nodes with Drupals devel-module, but the saved file contains corrupt data:

```
<Reference ID="72c24cb5-c422-41c8-9047-cd43536d0f1f" ReferenceType="CollectedWorks" CreatedBy="i" CreatedOn="2012-11-26T16:15:45" ModifiedBy="i" ModifiedOn="2013-02-26T13:45:38" SequenceNumber="28160">
  <Authors>b332174e-9007-4e30-9da6-f79e5bb6bb08</Authors>
  <CitationKeyUpdateType>Automatic</CitationKeyUpdateType>
  <PlaceOfPublication>Paris</PlaceOfPublication>
  <Publishers>a38d2bf6-aba5-49de-8783-291c0bc58165</Publishers>
  <Subtitle>Item Caii Iulii Solini Polyhistor ex veteribvs libris emendatvs</Subtitle>
  <Title>Cl. Salmasii Plinianae exercitationes In Caii Iulii Solini Polyhistora</Title>
  <Year>1629</Year>
<@attributes/></Reference>
```

This is from the original file:

```
<Reference ID="72c24cb5-c422-41c8-9047-cd43536d0f1f" ReferenceType="CollectedWorks" CreatedBy="i" CreatedOn="2012-11-26T16:15:45" ModifiedBy="i" ModifiedOn="2013-02-26T13:45:38" SequenceNumber="28160">
  <Authors>b332174e-9007-4e30-9da6-f79e5bb6bb08</Authors>
  <CitationKeyUpdateType>Automatic</CitationKeyUpdateType>
  <PlaceOfPublication>Paris</PlaceOfPublication>
  <Publishers>a38d2bf6-aba5-49de-8783-291c0bc58165</Publishers>
  <Subtitle>Item Caii Iulii Solini Polyhistor ex veteribvs libris emendatvs</Subtitle>
  <Title>Cl. Salmasii Plinianae exercitationes In Caii Iulii Solini Polyhistora</Title>
  <Year>1629</Year>
</Reference>
```

Any idea how the <@attributes/> comes into the data?

Comment: Random Guess: dpm($reference) dumps the XML node and your are not looking at the save file but the dump?

Comment: No, forget the dpm-dump. The code I've posted is from the saved file.

Comment: Can you remove the looping and showing of the reference-nodes please? Does that make a difference? If not: since you don't edit the XML, consider just using the `copy` function over `asXml()`

Comment: Thanks Gordon! All I had to do is erase the dpm() function at that place. Don't know what made it act like that, because at different other positions in the code I can use it and it doesn't corrupts my file.

Comment: Rather than editing the title to read "Solved:", you need to accept an answer. [It is fine to add your own answer and then accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the `dpm()` debug function is actually modifying the object accidentally, corrupting it.

Digging through [the source tree on drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/8) it looks like that function uses a library called Krumo for its pretty-printing where available.

While I can't see the exact cause of that particular problem, it certainly does poke things into objects - e.g. [the `hive()` method](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/krumo!class.krumo.php/function/krumo%3A%3A_hive/8) adds a "recursion marker".

Bottom line, that's probably not a good function to use with SimpleXML (it's unlikely to give a good view of the object anyway, compared to [a specialist function which understands SimpleXML's "magic"](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug)).

Comment: I think we should really pick a well reference question for this simplexml magic stuff we can easily link. It's quite often an issue and a reference question could collect all those good resources and explanations. It's sad to see krumo fails on this btw.